# How pass Balance in loosely coupled pallet?

Tags: loose-coupling

I want to pass Balance to SchellingGameSharedSource.

Here is my code:

```
use sortition_sum_game::types::{SumTreeName};
use schelling_game_shared::types::{SchellingGameType};
type AccountIdOf<T> = <T as frame_system::Config>::AccountId;
type BalanceOf<T> = <<T as Config>::Currency as Currency<AccountIdOf<T>>>::Balance;

#[pallet::config]
    pub trait Config: frame_system::Config {
        type Event: From<Event<Self>> + IsType<<Self as frame_system::Config>::Event>;
        type SchellingGameSharedSource: SchellingGameSharedLink<SumTreeName=SumTreeName, SchellingGameType = SchellingGameType, BlockNumber = Self::BlockNumber, AccountId= Self::AccountId, Balance=BalanceOf<T>>;
        type Currency: ReservableCurrency<Self::AccountId>;
    }
```

SchellingGameSharedLink trait

```
pub trait SchellingGameSharedLink {
    type SumTreeName;
    type SchellingGameType;
    type BlockNumber;
    type AccountId;
    type Balance;

fn apply_jurors_helper_link(
        key: Self::SumTreeName,
        game_type: Self::SchellingGameType,
        who: Self::AccountId,
        stake: Self::Balance,
    ) -> DispatchResult;

}
```

Passing `Balance=BalanceOf<T>` gives error can't find type T in this scope
and passing `Balance=Self::Balance>` gives error associated type `Balance` not found

Comment: `Balance=BalanceOf<T>` to `Balance=BalanceOf<Self>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass `Balance = BalanceOf<Self>`.

In the context of the trait there is no generic parameter `T` defined, so you can not use it. Your `BalanceOf` is written in a way that it assumes that `T` is something that implements your `Config` trait. So, if you want to use it in the context of your trait declaration, you need to pass `Self` as parameter to `BalanceOf`.